# using HTTP client for Angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular-http

I was following this here to learn how to work with the Http client.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/

In it, there is a reference to use `URLSearchParams`

but - from what I have seen in another post `URLSearchParams` has been depricated.

As of now, the service I am using requires HTTP access. I have the following in order to import HTTP functionality.

```
// import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
// import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
```

What is the best way to use HTTP functionality for Angular 5?

TIA

**UPDATE**

I tried the following but got the error:

> ```
> core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
>   StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]:
> ```

TIA

```
[... snip ...]

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/shareReplay';


// import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
// import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

// import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

// import { HttpClient, HttpParams  } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // HttpModule,
    // HttpClientModule,
    // HttpClient,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [ AppSettings, AdminServicesService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**admin.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from 'app/pages/auth-admin/admin-model/user';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { workers } from 'cluster';

// OLD: => import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http/src/client';
// import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

[... snip ...]
```

**And I got the following error**

```
core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at _createClass (core.js:10915)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10889)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at _createClass (core.js:10915)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10889)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
```

Comment: Uncomment ``// import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`` and ``// HttpClientModule,`` in your app.module.ts.

Comment: Thanks - that worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular v4.3+ you should use new `HttpClient` which you should import from `@angular/common/http` like this:

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`.

For `URLSearchParams` you should use `HttpParams`, which you also should import from `@angular/common/http` like this:

`import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';`.

Here is an example for simple `GET`-request with new `HttpClient`:

```
  getSomething(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(url, { headers: yourHeaders })
      .catch((e) => this.yourHandleErrorFunction(e));
  }
```

Here is an example with `HttpParams`:

```
  getAttachment(url: string, attachmentId: number, width: number = 0, height: number = 0): Observable<File> {
    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    httpParams = httpParams.set('height', height.toString());
    httpParams = httpParams.set('width', width.toString());
    return this.http
      .get<File>(url, { headers: yourHeaders, params: httpParams, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
      .catch((e) => this.yourHandleError(e));
  }
```

Read the official angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) for `HttpClient`.

Comment: thanks for the information. I made changes and put the results in the post.

Comment: @CaseyHarrils you should provide ``HttpClientModule`` in ``imports: []`` in your app.module.ts. This HttpClientModule should be imported from ``@angular/common/http``.